# 3D drawing to PDF

Tags: python, pdf-generation, pyprocessing

I cannot work out how to render a 3D drawing to a PDF file in the python mode of [Processing](http://py.processing.org/). Here's an example of a drawing:

```
size(400, 400, P3D)
noStroke()
background(0)
directionalLight(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, -100)
translate(width / 2, height / 2, 0)
sphere(100)
```

I have included `add_library("pdf")` at the beginning of the script, and have experimented with [`createGraphics`](http://py.processing.org/reference/createGraphics.html), but I have not been able to get it to render a 3D image. Drawing 2D images to PDF works fine.